# Java Generics: Can't get syntax right

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to write a custom UI component (on android) that will display a text edit control along with two buttons which can be clicked up or down. Up increments the number in the edit control and down decrements it.

I'd like this class to be generic on the numeric type i.e. i'd like to specialize the class for int and float types.

I've been reading this nice [Java Generics Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf) but my particular implementation doesn't seem to compile. Here's what I have got:

```
public class NumberPicker<T> extends LinearLayout implements OnClickListener,
        OnFocusChangeListener, OnLongClickListener {

    public interface OnChangedListener<T> {
        void onChanged(NumberPicker<T> picker, T oldVal, T newVal);
    }

    public interface Formatter<T> {
        String toString(T value);
    }

    // Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T
    public static final NumberPicker.Formatter<T> TWO_DIGIT_FORMATTER =
            new NumberPicker.Formatter<T>() {
                public String toString(T value) {
                        // Do something with T value
                }
        };
}
```

I'm getting the following compiler error in the declaration of the `TWO_DIGIT_FORMATTER`:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T

Can someone please help me with the syntax. Coming from C++ I understand generic well enough and am aware of some of the differences between the two. I just need help with the syntax.

I tried changing to:

```
        // "Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token"
    public static final NumberPicker.Formatter<int> TWO_DIGIT_FORMATTER =
            new NumberPicker.Formatter<int>() {
                public String toString(int value) {
                    return mFmt.toString();
                }
        };
```

This gives "Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `T` parameter belongs to a `NumberPicker` instance, each instance can have a different value to it, so it can't be relied on in a static field of the class.

Nor can it be referenced in the `public interface Formatter<T>`, as interface members are by default static.

One way to work around this is:

1. `TWO_DIGIT_FORMATTER`, being a constant should have the parameter bound. When you think about it, an unbound parameter doesn't really make much sense in this situation.
2. `Formatter` can have its own separate parameter, checked when you pass it to a `NumberPicker` instance. (This is already done implicitly in `OnChangedListener`.)

So your code will be something like this:

```
public class NumberPicker<T>  {

    public interface OnChangedListener<Y> { //
        void onChanged(NumberPicker<Y> picker, Y oldVal, Y newVal);
    }

    public interface Formatter<X> {
        String toString(X value);
    }

    public void setFormatter( Formatter<T> formatter ) { ... }

    public static final NumberPicker.Formatter<? extends Number> TWO_DIGIT_FORMATTER =
        new NumberPicker.Formatter<Number>() {
            public String toString(Number value) {
                    // Do something with T value
            }
        };

}
```

I replaced `T` with `X` and `Y` in the interface definitions to avoid confusion. The parameter of the interfaces is completely separate from the parameter of `NumberPicker` By giving them different names this becomes readily apparent.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have to do with syntax, it has to do with the fact that your type `T` is associated with *instances* of `NumberPicker`, while your `TWO_DIGIT_FORMATTER` is `static` and as such not associated with any instance of `NumberPicker`. So there is no type `T` for it to refer to.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this. I realize this and tried the other approach by specializing for type `int`. That gives me a different error (please see update)

Answer (score 0):

Your field `TWO_DIGIT_FORMATTER` is a static field, that is, a class field, not belonging to any specific instance. On the other hand, the type parameter `T` is getting resolved only when you  refer to a specific instance of `NumberPicker` where you have bound `T` to a concrete type. The type of `T` changes with different instances so naturally it has no meaning on a class field. You'll have to remove the `static` qualifier from `TWO_DIGIT_FORMATTER` and then you'll have to access it through an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use generic in static method. Generic will paremetrize your instances, and static is not instance but class scope.

You can change it to (remove static):

```
public final NumberPicker.Formatter<T> TWO_DIGIT_FORMATTER = ...
```